# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRINT

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have searched and can not find anything on T_PRINT syntax errors. So here it goes, I don't see how this is "unexpected". It is referring to the print "Your Staff Application has been posted" etc. line.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "globals.php";
if($_POST['app']) 
{ 
$db->query("INSERT INTO staffapps VALUES('',$userid,'{$_POST['pos']}','{$_POST['app']}')", $c)
or die
("Your staff application could not be processed. Make sure you have filled out the form completely!"); 
 
print "Your Staff Application has been posted for our staff to review, your results will be decided within 14 days! Good Luck!"; 
 
} 
else
 
print "<h3>Staff Application</h3>
 
 
<center><h8><b>Please read the <a href='stafftoc.php'><font color='yellow'>Terms & Conditions</font></a>before sending an application!</b>
 
<form action='staffapps.php' method='post'>
Position <select name='pos'><option value='3'>Admin</option><option value='5'>Secretary</option><option value='6'>Assistant</option></select>
 
Why do you deserve the position?
 
Please bare in mind that staff look for professional members so be sure to spell correctly with the right grammar and punctuation!
 
If your staff application appears un-professional, it will be dismissed! 
 
<textarea rows='7' cols='40' name='app'>{$_GET['app']}</textarea>
 
<input type='submit' value='Submit Application' /></form>";
 
$h->endpage;
?>
```

Comment: Also i am downloading netbeans, so no need to tell me to use an IDE (i read up on it) :D

Comment: after else where is "termination(;)" ?

Comment: You should really check the ``$_POST`` values before passing it to your database. Or use a prepared statement. ``PDO`` is a nice database wrapper. :)

Comment: @Mahesh.D If you're talking about the ``";`` for the ``print`` statement, then it's way down at the bottom just above ``$h->endpage;``.

Comment: right ninetwozero,I've mistaken

Comment: @JesperHaraldsson Error lies elsewhere perhaps? The code seems ok (on the surface). Make sure it isn't some caching issue, and that this is the code in the file you are testing.

Comment: Use braces for a start. That way you will not get caught with your trousers falling down!

Comment: For me this code doesn't contain any syntax-error. I can run it without any parse-error. http://codepad.org/mVupFsTn The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your code lines seem to have some funny trailing characters that shouldn't be there; here's a hexadecimal representation of them:

```
0xc2 0xa0
```

I've been told that this is a [non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm). Clearing those characters from your code should fix the issue.

Comment: I can't spot any such thing. How did you check?

Comment: @Cthulhu Using `php -r "print_r(explode('0a', bin2hex(file_get_contents('myscript.php'))));`

Comment: 0xc2 0xa0 is a non breaking space, nothing funny

Comment: I copied the code the OP posted, couldn't reproduce that. :(

Comment: @Cthulhu I copied it from the edit box instead of the Markdown render.

Comment: @Jack Even if it were some characters of that sort, they'd not cause an `unexpected T_PRINT` error right?

Comment: @Cthulhu It depends on where they are; if they were at the end of the previous line, then yes. Strange issue though, it's like OP used Word to author the PHP.

Comment: Hi Jack, I believe I deleted that now, yet I still receive the same error :(

Comment: @JesperHaraldsson Check *all* the line endings you have.

Comment: @Dr.Molle To PHP that *is* something funny actually :)

Comment: Check your if condition like this, hope it will solve your problem, 
if(isset($_POST['app']) && $_POST['app'] != '')